# Grid not respecting the width of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a grid containing 4 columns, each column can be displayed or not.
The first column should have the remaining space after all other columns have been filled.
The column's parent div must have a fixed size.
The problem is that the width of the parent div is not being respected by the auto property.

HTML:

```
<div class="top-row">
  <div *ngIf="isClient">{{'CLIENT HISTORY'}}</div>
  <div>{{residence}}</div>
  <div class="parent-grid">
    <div class="first-name">{{firstName}}</div>
    <div class="second-name">{{secondName}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="hasThirdName" class="third-name">{{thirdName}}</div>  
    <div class="last-name">{{lastName}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-row {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  background-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto auto auto;
}

.first-name {
  background-color: blue;
  text-overflow: fade
}

.second-name {
  background-color: green;
}

.third-name {
  background-color: gray;
}

.last-name {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

TypeScript:

```
  isClient = true;
  hasThirdName = false;
  residence = 'MY ADDRESS'
  firstName = "NAME VERY LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
  secondName = 'SECOND NAME LONGGGGGGG'
  thirdName = 'THIRD NAME'
  lastName = 'LAST NAMEEEEEEEE'
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)